# How to show text completly when sizedbox take space in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

i used Expanded(Sizedbox()) between my Text Widgets and this happended :

[image]

How can i prevent what that happened for my Text ?

this is my code :

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Awaiting Deposit',
                    style: regularTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Awaiting Confirmation',
                    style: regularTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Perform Exchange',
                    style: regularTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Done',
                    style: regularTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 12),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

when i Used Expanded(Sizedbox()) between my text Widgets my text dosent show properly
example :
awaiting Deposit shows awaitin g ....

Comment: use a smaller font size or give enough space so that text can fit.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://dartpad.dev/?id=edbb1d02d20b7d7d22168782b224a6c8 resize the right side to emulate small screen

In place of Expanded Use Fitted Box with \n like

```
           FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: Text(
            'Awaiting\nDeposit',
            //style: regularTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 12),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            maxLines: 2,
          )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use softWrap:true inside Text widget.